# Displaying both duplicate and non-duplicate values with some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**i have a query that executes through multiple condition and the result is as:**

#### Code    - Name    - Code2

```
a     abc     a.1
a     abc     a.2
a     abc     a.3
a     abc     a.4

b     bad     b.1
b     bad     b.2
b     bad     b.3
```

i need the resultant to be displayed as

#### Code    - Name    - Code2

```
a      abc      a.1
                a.2
                a.3
                a.4

b      bad      b.1
                b.2
                b.3
```

is it possible using T-SQL?     
i'm using SQL Server 2008-R2.

Comment: Not really same result, but you can achieve kind of using `xml path`

Comment: So you want your second thrid and forth row to only return data in the third column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Code, Name, Code2,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code, Name ORDER BY Code2)
   FROM dbo.TableName
   WHERE ....
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN '' ELSE Code END AS Code, 
    CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN '' ELSE Name END AS Name, 
    Code2
FROM CTE
```

Edit [**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a925/2/0) (thanks to bluefeet for data)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to get the result:

```
select 
  case when rn = 1 then code else '' end code,
  case when rn = 1 then name else '' end name,
  code2
from
(
  select code, name, code2,
    row_number() over(partition by code, name order by code2) rn
  from table3
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a925/1)

Comment: +1 for providing a demo first and for a similar (working) approach. Btw, how do you get the sample data so fast?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, I think I was slower posting because I was working on the demo! :)  You can use the *Text to DDL* option in SQL Fiddle and it goes much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this purely in SQL with a `row_number()` ranking:

```
with val_ranks as (
   select code,name,code2,
       row_number() over (partition by code order by code2) as rown
       from foo
)
select case when rown=1 then code else '' end as code,
       case when rown=1 then name else '' end as name,
       code2
   from val_ranks
   order by code2;
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c386/2).

Comment: Well, I see I was beaten to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
With cte(Col1,col2,col3) as
(
 Select 'a','abc','a.1'
 union all
 Select 'a',    'abc','a.2'
 union all
 Select 'a',    'abc','a.3'
 union all
 Select 'a',    'abc','a.4'
 union all
 Select 'b',    'bad','b.1'
 union all
 Select 'b',    'bad','b.2'
 union all
 Select 'b',    'bad','b.3'
 ),
 cte1 as
(Select * ,  
 row_number() over ( partition by col1,col2 order by (select 0)) as rn 
 from cte
)
 Select case when rn=1 then col1 else null end,
 case when rn=1 then col2 else null end,
 col3
 from cte1
 order by col3
```